# Play Framework 2 Java - Fire And Forget

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka, email, fire-and-forget

I have a signup where on successful registration I send the user an email to welcome them to the software. Currently the emails are not sent asynchronously, this causes the application to wait until the email is sent before returning a response letting me know it is successful. This is not ideal as 1) It doesnt really fit the Play ethos of scalability and 2) If I have multiple users signing up at the same time it will be very very slow.

I have a class that contains all of the methods for email (MailHelper.class), they are all static methods. I call them from another class (User.class) where the user signs up.

How can I use Akka to fire-and-forget the call to send an email? Do I need to do this in the User class or do I need to do this in the MailHelper class?

Below is the code I use to call the method that sends the email and below that is the code I use to actually send the email

Call the send email method:

```
MailHelper.sendRegistrationMail(userName, firstName, surname, registrationDate, emailToken);
```

Send the email:

```
public static void sendRegistrationMail(String userName, String firstName, String surname, String registrationDate, String emailToken) {
    MailerAPI mail = play.Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
    mail.setSubject("Welcome!");
    mail.setRecipient(userName);
    mail.setBcc("***@*****.com");
    mail.setFrom("Welcome");
    String body = views.html.emails.registration.render(userName, firstName, surname, registrationDate, emailToken).body();
    mail.sendHtml(body);
}
```

Any assistance would be great as I have never used Akka before and so far have only found Scala examples on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Akka task scheduler](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAkka) is exactly what you're looking for:

```
import play.libs.Akka;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public static void sendRegistrationMail(String userName, String firstName, String surname, String registrationDate, String emailToken) {
    Akka.system().scheduler().scheduleOnce(
        Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MailerAPI mail = play.Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
                mail.setSubject("Welcome!");
                mail.setRecipient(userName);
                mail.setBcc("***@*****.com");
                mail.setFrom("Welcome");
                String body = views.html.emails.registration.render(userName, firstName, surname, registrationDate, emailToken).body();
                mail.sendHtml(body);
            }
        },
        Akka.system().dispatcher()
    );
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate, works like a dream. I had to make the variables inside the run method final but thats no problem